# problem with cloned field

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

i have this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/xP9Bx/) that wotks well

now i am trying to change `<input id="input1" />` to `<div id="input1"> </div>` [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/J7sMr/).

The problem is the id, it is supposed change, like input1, input2, but in the second example the new divs always have the same id.

In the first example the name of the id's are input1, input2, input3,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved

```
 $('#btnAdd').click(function() {
        $('.btnDel:disabled').removeAttr('disabled');
        var c = $('.clonedInput:first').clone(true);
            c.children('div').attr('id','input'+ (++inputs) ).val('');
            c.children(':button').attr('name','btnDelete'+ (inputs) );
        $('.clonedInput:last').after(c);
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

You are setting the attribute "name" not "id", so your code should read:

```
$('#btnAdd').click(function() {
    $('.btnDel:disabled').removeAttr('disabled');
    var c = $('.clonedInput:first').clone(true);
        c.children(':text').attr('id','input'+ (++inputs) ).val('');
        c.children(':button').attr('id','btnDelete'+ (inputs) );
    $('.clonedInput:last').after(c);
});
```

Comment: nop, the name of the id is always input1. The alteration that you suggest is relative to the delete btn